# Creating a rule with the Windows Firewall API that applies to all applications run by a service

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

I'm trying set up a firewall rule for a Windows service to deny all inbound and outbound TCP and UDP connections except a whitelist of hosts and ports using the Windows Service Hardening API, following the VBScript example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366327(v=vs.85).aspx).

Now, this service may spawn new processes (as it is a continuous integration build and test agent), so it's not sufficient to just set `NewOutboundRule.ApplicationName = "%systemDrive%\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe"` as in the example script above - I need a rule to applies to *all* applications run by the service.

However, if I try and set up a new inbound rule where the allegedly optional `ApplicationName` property isn't specified on the [`INetFw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365344(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, the call to add the new rule fails (at the line `wshRules.Add NewOutboundRule` in the script above).  Everything else is correct, as if I specify the `ApplicationName`, the call succeeds.

Is there some way to create rules that apply to all possible values of `ApplicationName`, or some alternative way of doing this?

Comment: At a guess, if you specify a service name you also have to specify an application name.  Do service rules apply to child processes in the first place?  You might need to get the service itself to set the firewall rules for its own children in real-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some experimentation, it turns out that the WSH rules work like this:  The call to `INetFwServiceRestriction::RestrictService` (with `restrictService=TRUE`) only needs to contain the name of the primary executable which is called to start the service.  If that process spawns a new process using any other executable, by default that new process has ALL inbound and outbound network connections blocked.  This is true even if exceptions have been added for the primary executable via `INetFwServiceRestriction::Rules`.

So, if secondary executables run by the service need network access, it's necessary to add explicit `INetFwRule` exceptions for these executables as well.  This makes sense - the call to `RestrictService` blocks everything, and then a whitelist of exceptions which include the application names can be added.